# Time limit on repeating the shemona esra after forgetting to include an insertion

Tags: time, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, rosh-chodesh-new-month

If a person forgets to say yaaleh vyavo for rosh chodesh during the shemonah esre, I understand they are supposed to go back and repeat the shemonah esre, this time saying yaaleh vyavo.  Is there a time limit to do this?  For example, say I forgot it was rosh chodesh, don't say yaaleh vyavo for rosh chodesh during the shemonah esre, then an hour or two later, suddenly remember it is rosh chodesh, is it too late to go back and do the shemonah esre all over again?

Comment: Quick answer, no sources: There is no time limit. It's as if you did not say it; you would even [say Tashlumin](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/21809/5) at the next Tefillah if you did not repeat it within the Zeman.

Comment: FYI, re "If a person forgets to say yaaleh vyavo for rosh chodesh during the shemonah esre, I understand they are supposed to go back and repeat the shemonah esre, this time saying yaaleh vyavo": only at _shacharis_ and _mincha_.