# Tashlumin for a missing bracha - What if one forgot "veten tal omatar" on friday mincha

Tags: halacha, shabbat, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, geshem-tal-ruach

If one forgets the "veten tal omatar livracha" phrase in the ashkenazi nussach, they must pray again (if they have finished the whole prayer). What happens if one forgot on mincha on friday, and the sun has set and it is now shabbat.

Do they say Maariv twice since mincha "didn't count"
or do they not, since shabbat marriv doesn't mention it either.

I have seen this discussed in halacha with regard to other additions (yaaleh Veyavo, al hanisim...) but I am not certain the same logic applied there applies here.

Thanks

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21807/do-you-do-a-tashlumin-make-up-on-a-shemoneh-esreh-if-you-later-realize-that-y

Comment: @DoubleAA yes IMO.

Comment: question is not the same. second answer address the issue but does not rule on Veten Tal umatar

Comment: @YaakovPinsky How is this question not a subset of that question? And why would you expect any answer here to "rule" on anything?

Comment: rule is a bad choice of words. I didn't find that question when I asked this one. How would one ask a "subset question"?

Comment: @DoubleAA not a dupe, since one can technically daven tefillah shel chol on Shabbos

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach, as noted in various sources in Halacha (see articles [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/112330), and [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/2764), quoting the Piskei Teshuvah, and [here](http://www.shut-halacha.co.il/q/%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%97-%D7%98%D7%9C-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99-5168) in the name of Rav Ovadiah in Yalkut Yosef, although some disagree, see there) **is to not repeat the Amidah at all**.

This [Dirshu article](http://www.dirshu.co.il/%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%96-%D7%9E%D7%A8-%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9A-%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%AA/) is the most thorough in its sourcing, actually citing commentaries and poskim on what to practically do, and they conclude that it is a **Machlokes** as well, whether **to say two tefillos of Shabbos** (Rav Chaim Soloveitchik and Rabbi Tzvi Pesach Frank, followed by Rabbi Chaim Kanievski), or **not to repeat the Amidah** (Sha'arei Teshuvah and Magen Avraham OC 108, followed by Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach and Rav Yosef Shalom Eliyashiv):

> כד. שכח לומר טל ומטר במנחה בערב שבת, נחלקו האם מתפלל מעריב ב' פעמים [כיון דבין כך אינו מזכיר שם]. יש מדמים ליעלה ויבוא [כשר"ח הי' ביום שישי], דאינו חוזר כיון דא"א לעשות תנאי בשבת, דאין תפילת נדבה בשבת (שע"ת סי' קח, מג"א שם סקט"ז) וי"א דאינו דומה וחייב לחזור (הגר"ח בסטנסיל סי' א. שדת הר צבי א נד) ולמעשה י"א שלא יתפלל תפילת תשלומין כלל (הליכות שלמה פ"ח הערה 82 , הגרי"ש אלישיב. ועי' הסבר לזה בשיעורי הגרי"ש ע"מ ברכות מהרב ב.צ. קוק עמ' שיג) וי"א שיתפלל ערבית פעמיים (לגשמים בעיתם מהגר"ח קניבסקי)

This [somewhat lomdish article](http://beinenu.com/sites/default/files/alonim/103_98_78.pdf) discusses the issue in depth. Interestingly, it appears to suggest that a person should say Shemoneh Esrei on Friday night up to Birchas Hashanim (and possibly further), and say Vesein Tal Umatar during it, and then mention Shabbos, but this is not accepted customarily.

Comment: @JoelK yes, sorry, fixed now